# How to convert Yii view page to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, yii

I created a project using Yii framework, now I want convert the view page to PDF. Please help me to find an extension to do that.

I did a search and found examples, but those aren't Yii extensions, and I do not know how to implement them. Please give me some tutorials on how to convert the view page data to a PDF.

View page code:

> ```
>  <div class="row">    
>
>   <div class="row-column1">
>           <?php echo CHtml::label('Reg. Number. :','student_enroll_no'); ?>
>       <?php echo $info->student_enroll_no;?> 
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="row-column2">
>           <?php echo CHtml::label('Adm. Date :','student_adm_date'); ?>
>       <?php if($info->student_adm_date != NULL)
>           echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($info->student_adm_date));?>
>   </div>
>
> </div>
>
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="row-column1">
>       <?php echo CHtml::label('Student Name :','student_first_name'); ?>
>       <?php echo $info->student_first_name;?>
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="row-column2">
>   <?php echo CHtml::label('Enroll No. :','student_mobile_no'); ?>   
>       <?php echo $info->student_mobile_no;?>
>       
>       
>   </div>
>   
>   
> </div>
>
>
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="row-column1">
>    <?php echo CHtml::label('Fathers Name :','student_last_name'); ?>
>       <?php echo $info->student_last_name;?>
>       <!--<?php echo CHtml::label('Gender :','student_gender'); ?>
>       <?php echo $info->student_gender;?>-->
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="row-column3">
>    <?php echo CHtml::label('Mothers Name :','student_mother_name'); ?>
>       <?php echo $info->student_mother_name;?>
>        <!-- <?php echo CHtml::label('Date of Birth :','student_dob'); ?>
>   <?php   if($info->student_dob != NULL)
>       echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($info->student_dob));?>-->
>   </div>
> </div>
>
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="row-column1">
>   <?php echo CHtml::label('Gender :','student_gender'); ?>
>       <?php echo $info->student_gender;?>
>   <!--<?php echo CHtml::label('Course :','student_transaction_course_id'); ?>
>       <?php
>           echo !empty($model->student_transaction_course_id) ? $model->relCourse->course_name : 'N/A';
>       
>       ?>-->
>       
>         
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="row-column2">
>    <?php echo CHtml::label('Date of Birth :','student_dob'); ?>
>   <?php   if($info->student_dob != NULL)
>       echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($info->student_dob));?>
>       <!--<?php echo CHtml::label('Year :','student_academic_term_period_tran_id'); ?>
>        <?php echo $model->Rel_student_academic_terms_period_name->academic_term_period;?>-->
>   </div>  
> </div>
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="row-column1">
> <?php echo CHtml::label('Category :','title'); ?>
>       <?php echo $info->title;?>
>       
>         
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="row-column2">
>       <?php echo CHtml::label('Email ID :','student_email_id_1'); ?>                          <?php echo $info->student_email_id_1; ?>
>   </div>  
> </div>
>
>   
>
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="row-left">
>   <?php echo CHtml::label('Course :','student_transaction_course_id'); ?>
>       <?php
>           echo !empty($model->student_transaction_course_id) ? $model->relCourse->course_name : 'N/A';
>       
>       ?>
>       
>        <!-- <?php echo CHtml::label('Blood Group :','student_living_status'); ?>
>         <?php echo $info->student_living_status; ?>-->
>   </div>
>
>   <div class="row-column3">
>   
>        <!-- <?php echo CHtml::label('Nationality :','student_transaction_nationality_id'); ?>
>         <?php if($model->student_transaction_nationality_id!=null)
>       echo $model->Rel_Nationality->nationality_name; 
>   ?>-->
>   <?php echo CHtml::label('Year :','student_academic_term_period_tran_id'); ?>
>        <?php echo $model->Rel_student_academic_terms_period_name->academic_term_period;?>
>   </div>
>
> </div>
>
> <div class="row">
>   <div class="row-left">
>         <?php echo CHtml::label('Subjects :','languages_known1'); ?>
>         <?php 
>       $knwLang = "";
>       if($lang->languages_known1)
>       $knwLang =  $lang->Rel_Langs1->languages_name; 
>       if($lang->languages_known2)
>       $knwLang .= ", ".$lang->Rel_Langs2->languages_name;
>       if($lang->languages_known3)
>       $knwLang .= ", ".$lang->Rel_Langs3->languages_name;
>       echo $knwLang;
>   ?>
>
>   </div>
> </div>
>
>   <div class="row last">
>   
>       <?php echo ('_____________________Note -Click on edit and update DoB , Subjects and upload photo ,Enroll no. .'); ?>
>       
>   
>
> </div>
> ```

Answer (score 4):

here you will get extension with examples.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/

I'm using :
http://www.mpdf1.com/

you can download and create extension

Download this package:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/files/yii-pdf-0.3.2.zip

refer this forum for usage:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/44211-mpdf-header/

Answer (score 3):

You can use htmlpdf of yii extension by following given below points.
1. download extension  yii-pdf-0.3.2.zip from [pdf extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/pdf/)  extract zip file and put in your yii project under protected/extension

2.download html2pdf zip from here [html2pdf](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phphtml2pdf/) extract zip file and put it in to protected/extension

3. Go to protected/config/main.php
   go to component array and put this
         `'ePdf' => array(
           'class' => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',
             'params' => array(
               'HTML2PDF' => array(
               'librarySourcePath' => 'ext.html2pdf.*',
                'classFile' => 'html2pdf.class.php'
                 ),
                ),
              ),`
4. If you get TCPDF ERROR do go to extension/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php find output function write a line before return statement    `ob_end_clean();`